# When using cgo ; where/when is the performance overhead?

Tags: algorithm, cgo

I understand that when using `cgo` there is a performance hit taken for every go -> C function call. When trying to optimize my program(s), I would like to know where the lag will be added so that I can reduce these occurrences. So *in hypothetical arbitrary values* (as I don't have actual call timings)...

**If (starting assumptions)**

| Call type | time (arbitrary unit)
|--- |---
| `go->go` | 1
| go->C     | 10

**Questions, Does:**
`C->go` = `10` as well?
*How about:*

`go -> C -> C` ?= `20` *or* ~`11`?

`go -> C -> C -> go`  ?=? (*equals what?*)

**Essentially**,  do `C->go` , and `C-C` calls incur the same penalty as `go->C` and if so, when chained, does this penalty multiply?
That is `go->C->C->go` = ( 3 * `go->C` ) ?

I hope this isn't too arbitrary a question, I was hoping someone else has had the same need and had tested. Thanks!

Comment: As I understand it, the performance penalty is incurred only when crossing the C/Go boundary. go -> C -> C would incur the penalty once, not twice, while go-> C -> C -> go would incur it twice, not three times.

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret the question with these arbitrary values -- there is a context switch going between C and Go. C runs in a C context, Go runs in a Go context.

Comment: Thanks gentlemen, I appreciate the insight. And @JimB I'm sorry for the original formatting of the question - I wrote it some so hopefully it makes more sense. If I ever get to test I will post back here, but I am tentatively taking the answer as simply the language boundary/context crossing bring the determining factor rather than anything in C land incurring a hit past the first crossover. (Thus `go->C->go` = 20 but go `go->C->C->go` would be 21 and not 30) Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @ehiller: `go->C->go` and `go->C->C->go` are the same thing. If the C code isn't doing anything there's no reason to call it, so any call into C must include some number of C->C calls. Go can't really effect the internal execution of the C code.

Comment: The benchmarks say go->C is pretty miniscule overhead. Just a few nanoseconds per call. So if thats all your doing, then you should be able to ignore the overhead.

Answer (score 1):

The benchmarks say go->C is pretty miniscule overhead. Just a few nanoseconds per call. So if thats all your doing, then you should be able to ignore the overhead.

C->go on the otherhand is supposed to have rather significant overhead. On the order of starting a new go program. So its best to avoid that directly if possible. Just rewrite your application, if possible, to have go->C to check on things or get the response, so you can skip the C->go and instead just have go->go.